# Employee scheduling with preference for consecutive days

Tags: c#, or-tools

My C# program is based on [Google's Employee Scheduling example](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling). One difference from the example, however, is that instead of working just with hard constraints I've added penalties when certain scenarios occur (for example, instead of failing if there aren't enough people to cover a shift it tries to minimize the penalties associated with low coverage). I've borrowed this concept from [a different tutorial I found online](https://medium.com/@mobini/solving-the-nurse-rostering-problem-using-google-or-tools-755689b877c0).

```
var objBoolSum = LinearExpr.WeightedSum(objBoolVars, objBoolCoeffs);
var objIntSum = LinearExpr.WeightedSum(objIntVars, objIntCoeffs);

model.Minimize(objBoolSum + objIntSum);
```

I'm adapting the example program to schedule volunteers who must travel to the job site and stay overnight. What I want to add next is a preference for working consecutive days in order to reduce the number of trips.

That is to say, Single-day assignments are allowed, but multiple is preferred.

For example, a scheduled like `[Yes, Yes, Yes, No, No]` would be preferred over `[Yes, No, Yes, Yes, No]`, which is still better than `[Yes, No, Yes, No, Yes]`. Any of those schedules could be permissible if necessary.

I feel like there is probably a technique for achieving this that I just haven't learned about yet. Suggestions?

Comment: May I ask why you seem to be using Hungarian Notation here?

Comment: There isn't enough context on the scope of the problem here to be sure, but one idea you might try is to introduce a binary variable for when a sequence of assignments starts.  The sequence can have arbitrary length.  Then you must link the "coverage" variable back to (1) having started the sequence and (2) the sequence being contiguous up to the coverage time.  Several examples:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74436487/or-tools-nurse-scheduling-prevent-shift-gaps-with-binary-constraints/74436740#74436740

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62633288/how-to-make-limited-bundling-constraint-in-variable-selection-for-maximization-p/62643178#62643178

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76858056/shift-scheduling-optimization-using-linear-programming-in-pulp/76871673#76871673

Comment: There is actually a C# example using CP-SAT from OR-Tools that does it.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at this complete example:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/dotnet/ShiftSchedulingSat.cs

In particular the soft sequence constraint:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/1d696f9108a0ebfd99feb73b9211e2f5a6b0812b/examples/dotnet/ShiftSchedulingSat.cs#L350

```
/// <summary>
    /// Sequence constraint on true variables with soft and hard bounds.
    /// This constraint look at every maximal contiguous sequence of variables
    /// assigned to true. If forbids sequence of length &lt; hardMin or &gt;
    /// hardMax. Then it creates penalty terms if the length is &lt; softMin or
    /// &gt; softMax.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model">The sequence constraint is built on this
    /// model.</param> <param name="works">A list of Boolean variables.</param>
    /// <param name="hardMin">Any sequence of true variables must have a length of
    /// at least hardMin.</param> <param name="softMin">Any sequence should have a
    /// length of at least softMin, or a linear penalty on the delta will be added
    /// to the objective.</param> <param name="minCost">The coefficient of the
    /// linear penalty if the length is less than softMin.</param> <param
    /// name="softMax">Any sequence should have a length of at most softMax, or a
    /// linear penalty on the delta will be added to the objective.</param> <param
    /// name="hardMax">Any sequence of true variables must have a length of at
    /// most hardMax.</param> <param name="maxCost">The coefficient of the linear
    /// penalty if the length is more than softMax.</param> <param name="prefix">A
    /// base name for penalty literals.</param> <returns>A tuple (costLiterals,
    /// costCoefficients) containing the different penalties created by the
    /// sequence constraint.</returns>
    static (IEnumerable<BoolVar> costLiterals, IEnumerable<int> costCoefficients)
        AddSoftSequenceConstraint(CpModel model, BoolVar[] works, int hardMin, int softMin, int minCost, int softMax,
                                  int hardMax, int maxCost, string prefix)
    {
        var costLiterals = new List<BoolVar>();
        var costCoefficients = new List<int>();

        // Forbid sequences that are too short.
        foreach (var length in Range(1, hardMin))
        {
            foreach (var start in Range(works.Length - length + 1))
            {
                model.AddBoolOr(NegatedBoundedSpan(works, start, length));
            }
        }

        // Penalize sequences that are below the soft limit.

        if (minCost > 0)
        {
            foreach (var length in Range(hardMin, softMin))
            {
                foreach (var start in Range(works.Length - length + 1))
                {
                    var span = NegatedBoundedSpan(works, start, length).ToList();
                    var name = $": under_span(start={start}, length={length})";
                    var lit = model.NewBoolVar(prefix + name);
                    span.Add(lit);
                    model.AddBoolOr(span);
                    costLiterals.Add(lit);
                    // We filter exactly the sequence with a short length.
                    // The penalty is proportional to the delta with softMin.
                    costCoefficients.Add(minCost * (softMin - length));
                }
            }
        }

        // Penalize sequences that are above the soft limit.
        if (maxCost > 0)
        {
            foreach (var length in Range(softMax + 1, hardMax + 1))
            {
                foreach (var start in Range(works.Length - length + 1))
                {
                    var span = NegatedBoundedSpan(works, start, length).ToList();
                    var name = $": over_span(start={start}, length={length})";
                    var lit = model.NewBoolVar(prefix + name);
                    span.Add(lit);
                    model.AddBoolOr(span);
                    costLiterals.Add(lit);
                    // Cost paid is max_cost * excess length.
                    costCoefficients.Add(maxCost * (length - softMax));
                }
            }
        }

        // Just forbid any sequence of true variables with length hardMax + 1
        foreach (var start in Range(works.Length - hardMax))
        {
            var temp = new List<ILiteral>();

            foreach (var i in Range(start, start + hardMax + 1))
            {
                temp.Add(works[i].Not());
            }

            model.AddBoolOr(temp);
        }

        return (costLiterals, costCoefficients);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer should provide the information necessary within the answer text itself, not simply a link.

Comment: The answer is complex, and the function itself misses the context.